# set the default value of TextField inside alertDialog

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i found the following sample code from Appcelerator's docs (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.AlertDialog-property-previewContext):

```
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title: 'Enter text',
    style: Ti.UI.iOS.AlertDialogStyle.PLAIN_TEXT_INPUT,
    buttonNames: ['OK']
  });
  dialog.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    Ti.API.info('e.text: ' + e.text);
  });
  dialog.show();
```

The problem is that i need to set a default value for the input text, but the documentation only shows the possibility to set a placeholder, but not a default value for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building for Android, you can use `androidView` property to add a custom `View` that contains the `TextField`. Then you can set `value` of the `TextField` to whatever your default value is.

For iOS, I don't know any way to achieve your goal other than making your own alert dialog. Perhaps there are some modules for this.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS , Actually you can`t

you can see the code of `TiUIAlertDialogProxy.m`

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/iphone/Classes/TiUIAlertDialogProxy.m#L164

There is no `TextField` value

```
 if ( (style == UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput) || (style == UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput) ) {
                [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                    textField.secureTextEntry = (style == UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput);
                    textField.placeholder = [TiUtils stringValue:[self valueForKey:@"placeholder"]] ?: @"";
                    textField.keyboardType = [TiUtils intValue:[self valueForKey:@"keyboardType"] def:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
                    textField.returnKeyType = [TiUtils intValue:[self valueForKey:@"returnKeyType"] def:UIReturnKeyDefault];
                    textField.keyboardAppearance = [TiUtils intValue:[self valueForKey:@"keyboardAppearance"] def:UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault];
                }];
            }
```

but you can make it manually , add this code

`textField.text = [TiUtils stringValue:[self valueForKey:@"text"]] ?: @"";`

then pass `text` property

```
var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
    text:'Init text',
    title: 'Enter text',
    style: Ti.UI.iOS.AlertDialogStyle.PLAIN_TEXT_INPUT,
    buttonNames: ['OK']
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `value`, `loginValue` and `passwordValue` properties to the alert-dialog using Titanium SDK 6.1.0 and later!